# PHP 7 Erro de sintaxe, ponto de interrogação antes de especificar o parâmetro

Tags: php, laravel

Eu desenvolvi um site em `Laravel` utilizando a versão `PHP 7.2`, quando subi para o servidor (*que está utilizando a versão 7.0 do* `PHP`) notei que estava dando um erro de sintaxe na seguinte linha

```
public function __construct(?string $test)
```

Essa linha pertence a um arquivo padrão do framework do `Laravel`

Aqui está o erro completo:

> `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/vhosts/placarama.com.br/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php on line 42`

Junto com ele tem outro erro

> `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0`

Alguem tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Eu acho que é a versão que não tem aquele recurso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A versão não corresponde ao novo recurso que se chama [Nullable types](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types) que foi introduzido na versão ***7.1***, então a ***7.0*** não tem esse recurso por isso dos erros.

<sub>**Referencia:** [Nullable types - PHP Versão 7.1](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types)</sub>